# Making sure user provides Y or N only

Tags: c++

my program is almost done. The only thing that I am having trouble with is at the end.

I ask the user if they would like to restart the program but with new inputs by inputting y, Y, N, or n ONLY and if they accidentally provide with another character then the program should tell them that it is invalid and to try providing a valid input.

```
  //Asking the user if they want to restart the program
            cout << "Do you want to start the program again and input new data? Y/N: ";
            cin >> option;

                //making sure that they actually input 'y', 'Y', 'n', or 'N'
                do {
                 cout << "That is an invalid input. Try again.\n";
                 cin >> option;
                 } while (((option != 'y') && (option != 'Y'))  ((option != 'n') && (option !='N')));
                system("CLS");
                cout << "Ok thank you for using my program. BYE!" << endl;
        } while (option == 'y' || option == 'Y');
```

Since I am still a beginner with C++ the only things that I have tried is switching the order of the conditions inside the while loop, but aside from that, I would not know.

Below is the whole code with comments in it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //This char is for the do...while loop
    char option;
    do {
        //variable names
        bool validInputStudent = false;
        bool validInputDay = false;
        int numStudents;
        float numHoursProg, numHoursBio, totalProg, totalBio, averageProg, averageBio;
        int student,day = 0;     // these are the counters for the loops
        int MAXDAY;
        cout << "This program will find the average number of hours a day"
             << " that a student spent programming over a set number of days? ";
        //This piece of code will make sure that the user inputs a numeric value
        do {
            cout << "\n\nHow many students are there? ";
            cin >> numStudents;
            //making sure that they input an actual number and not a letter bu accident
            if (!(validInputStudent = cin.good())){
                cout<< "That input is not valid! Try again!\n";
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
            }

        } while (!validInputStudent);

    //making sure that they enter a numeric value again
        do {
            cout << "\n\nHow many days did the student worked? ";
            cin >> MAXDAY;

            if (!(validInputDay = cin.good())){
                cout<< "That input is not valid! Try again!\n";
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
            }

        } while (!validInputDay);

        //This will add up the number of hours that they spent studying for each subject
            for(student = 1; student <= numStudents; student++)
            {
                totalProg = 0;
                totalBio = 0;
                for(day = 1; day <= MAXDAY; day++)
                {
                    bool validInputHProg = false;
                    bool validInputHBio = false;

                    //Making sure that the users input is a numeric value
                    do {
                        cout << "\n\nPlease enter the number of hours programming by student "
                             << student <<" on day " << day << ": ";
                        cin >> numHoursProg;

                         if (!(validInputHProg = cin.good())){
                        cout<< "That input is not valid! Try again!\n";
                        cin.clear();
                        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
                        }

                    } while (!validInputHProg);

                    //Making sure that the users input is a numeric value
                    do{
                        cout << "\n\nPlease enter the number of hours studying biology " << student << " on day "
                            << day << ": ";
                        cin >> numHoursBio;

                        if (!(validInputHBio = cin.good())){
                        cout<< "That input is not valid! Try again!\n";
                        cin.clear();
                        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
                        }

                    } while (!validInputHBio);

                    //Adding up all the hours per class
                    totalProg = totalProg + numHoursProg;
                    totalBio = totalBio + numHoursBio;
                }

                //Finding the average time spent studying per subject
                averageProg = totalProg / MAXDAY;
                averageBio = totalBio / MAXDAY;

                //This will find what subject the student spent studying the most
                if (averageBio > averageProg){
                    cout << "\n\nThe student spent more time studying Biology than programming" << endl;
                } else if (averageBio < averageProg){
                    cout << "\n\nThe student spent more time programming than studying Biology" << endl;
                } else if (averageBio = averageProg) {
                    cout << "\n\nThe student spent an even amount of time studying Biology and programming" << endl;
                }

            }

            //Asking the user if they want to restart the program
            cout << "Do you want to start the program again and input new data? Y/N: ";
            cin >> option;

                //making sure that they actually input 'y', 'Y', 'n', or 'N'
                do {
                 cout << "That is an invalid input. Try again.\n";
                 cin >> option;
                 } while (((option != 'y') && (option != 'Y'))  ((option != 'n') && (option !='N')));
                system("CLS");
                cout << "Ok thank you for using my program. BYE!" << endl;
        } while (option == 'y' || option == 'Y');
    return 0;
}
```

I just want the program not to accept any other characters or numbers that are not n, N, y, Y. If by any chance they do, the program should tell the user to try again. Currently no matter what I put it says that it is wrong. Even if I input the correct characters.

Comment: Please remove the `C#` tag.

Comment: Please provide [mcve] with emphasizes on **minimal**.

Comment: What is the issue?  Is it not compiling?  Not running correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `&&` between your valid options:

```
while (((option != 'y') && (option != 'Y'))  ((option != 'n') && (option !='N')));
//                                         &&
```

I'm surprised it compiles. It looks like you are using the first expression as a function where the second expression contains a `bool` argument to the function:

```
((option != 'y') && (option != 'Y'))  // the "function"
((option != 'n') && (option !='N'))   // the bool argument
```

So, add `&&` between them.

You are also doing what looks like comparisons, but are assignments:

`if(averageBio = averageProg)`

Check those out. You should probably use `==` between them.

Comment: OMG dude thanks. Can't believe I missed that.

Comment: You ACTUALLY helped

Comment: @GuillermoMolinaMatus Glad it helped! :)